# Node order in the stage (Javafx)

Tags: javafx

With following code (JavaFX 8) I get 4 rectangles (Cards). The rectangles were displayed with 15px shift. Last card is on the top of the Deck. How can I take with the right mouse event another cards to the top?
Another words, how can I `primaryStage` rebuild?

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.ImagePattern;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private static ObservableList<Rectangle> cardList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public static Rectangle getCard(int i) {

        Image card = new Image("file:C:\\Workspace\\pic\\" + i + "_12.png");

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100 + i * 15, 120, 71, 96);
        rect.setFill(new ImagePattern(card));

        rect.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                if (t.getButton().equals(MouseButton.SECONDARY)) {
                    rect.setStrokeWidth(2);
                    rect.setStroke(Color.YELLOW);
                }
            }
        });
        rect.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                if (t.getButton().equals(MouseButton.SECONDARY)) {
                    rect.setStrokeWidth(0);
                }
            }
        });
        return rect;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        primaryStage.setTitle("4 cards");
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            cardList.add(getCard(i));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            root.getChildren().addAll(cardList.get(i));
        }

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you have a title of "JavaFX stage order"? You only have one stage so there is no way to order it.  Maybe you want to change the stacking order of nodes in the scene?  Maybe you want to re-order nodes using [toFront()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#toFront--)?

Comment: @jewelsea I want with the right mouse click my cardList to reorder. And then see this in the scene. Thank you very much! toFront() is what I need.